# Combining different date and time columns to form a datetime value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to create a YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS AM/PM format (for e.g. 2017-01-01 12:00:00 AM) from
a. A date column that is of the DDMMMYYYY format (for e.g. 01JAN2017); and
b. A time column that is of the HH:MM:SS AM/PM (for e.g. 12:00:00 AM) format.

The AM/PM in (b) appears to be the biggest problem.

I've tried a few approaches from stack overflow
a. read.csv(parse_dates = [['date','time]]), and then re-arranging the date-time column using pd.to_datetime(df, format='%d%b%Y %H:%M:%S'). 
b. Converting 'date' using the datetime function and 'time' function to timedeltas using pd.time_delta before trying to concatenate both of them.
c. Looping([Combine date and time columns using datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42572744/combine-date-and-time-columns-using-datetime))
d. Writing a parser, and then including the parser into the pd.read_csv command together with parse_dates = [['date','time']]. ([Convert string date time to pandas datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501726/convert-string-date-time-to-pandas-datetime))

a. `df = pd.read_csv('a.csv',parse_dates=[['date','time']])
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format = format='%d%b%Y %H:%M:%S)`

b. `df = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df["Time"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Time"])
df["DateTime"] = df["Date"] + df["Time"]`

c. Same as the code in the link

d. Same as the code in the link

I received plenty of error messages on formats because the time column has the AM or PM portion after the HH:MM:SS portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_datetime` with `%I` for parse hour in 12H format with `%p` for parse `AM/PM`. Last if need in output `AM/PM` is necessary convert to strings by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('a.csv')

print (df)
        Date         Time
0  01JAN2017  12:00:00 AM

df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"] + ' ' +df["Time"],  format='%d%b%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
df["DateTime_str"] = df["DateTime"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')
print (df)
        Date         Time   DateTime            DateTime_str
0  01JAN2017  12:00:00 AM 2017-01-01  2017-01-01 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Sorry I have a follow-up question. How about if my date is first converted df['date_actual'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_actual'],format='%d%b%Y') - this is so that I can merge different dataframes together by date first, which yields 2017-01-01. How do I merge this with the time column containing values such as 12:00:00 AM? I tried pd.to_datetime again but I don't think it works